# Python Get rid of rows with Nans in only one column

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am new python, thank you for all your help in advance!

I am having a lot of trouble accomplishing something in Python that is very easy to do in Excel.

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'c1': [1,2,3,4,5],
         'c2': [4,6,7,None,3],
         'c3': [0,None,3,None,4]})
```

Notice I have `NaN` values in columns `c2` and `c3`.
I want to remove all rows with `NaN` in `c2`.

So the result should look like this:

```
c1: [1,2,3,5]
c2: [4,6,7,3]
c3: [0,Nan,3,4]
```

I tried all sorts of list comprehensions but they either contain bugs or won't give me the correct result.

I think this is close:

```
[x for x in df["c2"] if x != None]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a list comprehension, for a pure pandas solution:

```
df.dropna(subset=['c2'])
```

subset allows you to select columns to inspect.

Comment: Oh my god, I tried this method after searching through the documentation, but all I missed were the square [] brackets... Panda's documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html didn't tell me to add square brackets!!!

Comment: Yes, those brackets have got me before too ;), documentation does ask for array-like argument, but I agree, not intuitive when you are just passing one column!

Answer (score 0):

You're very close:

```
d = {'c1': [1,2,3,4,5],
     'c2': [4,6,7,None,3],
     'c3': [0,None,3,None,4]}
for k in d:
  d[k] = [x  for x in d[k]  if x != None] 
df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all your columns are stored as lists, you can use c2.index(None) to get the index of None in c2. Then remove that index from each list using pop(). More documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Given this data:

```
data = {
    'c1':  [4,6,7,None,3], 
    'c2': [4,6,7,None,3], 
    'c3': [0,None,3,None,4]
}
```

### Removal of the first instance:

The values of equal to `None` can most efficiently be removed as follows:

```
ind = data['c2'].index(None)
data['c2'].pop(ind)
```

You may wish to implement a function to automate this:

```
def remove(data_set, item, value):
    ind = data_set[item].index(value)
    return data_set.pop[ind]
```

### Removal of all instances:

Notice that this will remove only the first occurrence of `None`, or any other values. To remove them all occurrences efficiently and without iteration, you may wish to do as follows:

```
tmp = set(data['c2']) - set([None]*len(data['c2']))
data['c2'] = list(tmp)
```

or define a function:

```
def remove(data_set, item, value):
    response = set(data_set[item]) - set([value] * len(data_set[item]))
    return list(response)
```

whereby:

```
data['c2'] = remove(data, 'c2', None)
```

### Comparison of results:

All the above return this for `c2`:

```
[4, 6, 7, 3]
```

The first 2 solutions, applied to `c3`, return:

```
[0, 3, None, 4]
```

whereas the last 2 solutions, however, return as follows if applied to `c3`:

```
[0, 3, 4]
```

Hope you find this helpful.